# Default Padding/Margin on the left and right side of the navigation item

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, android-navigationview

I have created a new android project with Navigation Drawer Activity
[Navigation Drawer activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FVoc.jpg)

I did not perform any changes in the project and after creating the project I have directly run that project.
And I am getting proper output like the following:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs8SD.jpg)

Now the question is how to remove the padding/margin on the left and right side of the navigation item?
[Margin/Padding on Left & Right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpXkn.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the `NavigationView`'s attributes in `activity_main.xml`:

```
app:itemShapeInsetBottom="0dp"
app:itemShapeInsetTop="0dp"
app:itemShapeInsetEnd="0dp"
app:itemShapeInsetStart="0dp"
```

Comment: I have also tried one thing that, I changed the parent-theme in AppTheme style.
initially it's parent theme was material theme and i replaced with normal theme.